# Prove $P\left( A_n\right) = 0 \Longrightarrow P\left(\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} A^c_n\right)=1 $

Tags: probability, probability-theory

If $ (\Omega,F,P)$ is  a  probability  space  and $A_1, A_2..\in F$ Show   that
$$\ P\left( A_n\right) = 0 \Longrightarrow P\bigg(\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} A^c_n\bigg)=1$$

I don't know how to approach the problem

Comment: The statement as written is not true. Take $A_n = \Omega$ and $A_1 = \emptyset$. Then $P(A_n) = 1$, but also $P(\cup A_n^c) = 1$.

Comment: yeah..I wrote it wrong, my mistake

Comment: Isn't the case that $P(A_n^c) =1 - P(A_n)$?

Comment: @DaviBarreira How can you prove that such $n$ exists?

Answer (score 2):

If $P(A_m) = 0$, then $P(A_m^c)=1$. But $P(\cup_n A_n^c) \geq P(A_m^c)$, so the former is equal to $1$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $k\in\mathbb N$, such that $\mathbb P(A_k)=0$, then $\mathbb P(A^c_k)=1$. So, taking complements one gets,

$$\mathbb P\big[\bigcup_n A^c_n\big] = \mathbb P\Big[\Omega\setminus\bigcap_n A_n\Big]=\mathbb P\big[\bigcup_n(\Omega\setminus A_n)\Big]\geq \mathbb P\big[\Omega\setminus A_k\big] =1$$

But $A_1, A_2,\ldots\in\mathcal F$, is in the probability space, so $\mathbb P\big[\bigcup_n A^c_n\big]=1$.